# Automaton without stack for visibly pushdown languages

Tags: formal-languages, pushdown-automata

This paper [here](http://cliplab.org/~lbozzelli/CONCUR07.pdf) describes an alternating automaton which can recognize visibly pushdown langauges without using a stack. Unfortunately the transformation from NVPA to such an automaton is skipped in this paper. It also says:

> Due to the lack of space, for the omitted details we refer the interested reader to a forthcoming extended version of this paper.

but I actually can not find such a version.

Do you maybe have an alternative paper which explains this in more detail?

Comment: Have you tried writing an eMail to the author? She should know more about this than anyone else.